# xamarin shell: dynamically generate pages for routes

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I was trying out the newly released xamarin shell. Basically, I am trying out how to map the route to a dynamically generated page. I noticed the `RegisterRoute` has an overload that requires an object of type `RouteFactory`. I created a demo class for this:

```
class NavMan : RouteFactory
{
    private readonly string title;

    public NavMan(string title) : base()
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public override Element GetOrCreate()
    {
        return new ContentPage
        {
            Title = "tit: " + title,
            Content = new Label { Text = title }
        };
    }
}
```

Now, in the `App.cs` I create a register a demo route:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("batman", new NavMan("I am batman"));
```

I have tried several variations of setting up the `Shell` object. I mostly get blunt null pointers and need to guess what to change.

As of now, my `App` class's constructor has the following code:

```
var sea = new Shell();
var theItem = new FlyoutItem
{
    IsEnabled = true,
    Route = "batman"
};
sea.Items.Add(theItem);
sea.CurrentItem = theItem;
MainPage = sea;
```

This gives me a blunt null pointer too. All I am trying for now is to display the page of route "batman". Even a flyout or tab isn't mandatory.

**Update**

While not the aim, I at least got the app opening with the following:

```
var sea = new Shell();
Routing.RegisterRoute("batman", new NavMan("I am batman"));
var theItem = new ShellContent {
    Title = "hello 20",
    Route = "batman2",
    Content = new ContentPage {
        Content = new Button {
            Text = "Something shown",
            Command = new Command(async () => await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//batman"))
        }
    }
};
sea.Items.Add(theItem);
sea.CurrentItem = theItem;
MainPage = sea;
```

On clicking the button, it now shows me the following exception and never calls the `GetOrCreate` function.

> System.Exception: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

**Update 3**

Basically, I am looking for a way to bind a route to ShellContent in a way that it simply displays I mention the route property and it displays a page in the route. It doesn't make sense that I need to mention a route AND mention a content template for the page. The route is already mapped to a page.

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to do. What is the app requirement.

Comment: As of now, I am trying to get mentioned `RegisterRoute` overload working in any variation

Comment: @Neville,About RegisterRoute, you can take a look the Microsoft doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation

Comment: @CherryBu thanks. i looked at all docs for a while. (thats where the code was from) even downloaded their repos and tried it out. don't seem to find a direct solution for this

Comment: @CherryBu also don't show this overload